# Instantiate tricky class in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following class in C#:

```
class A<T> where T: A<T> {

}
```

How can I instantiate it?

Comment: What's the use case? I see code smell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create another class inheriting from `A` to stop the 'generic recursivity', e. g.

```
class TrickyA: A<TrickyA>
{
}
```

Then, you can create instances like this:

```
A<TrickyA> instance1 = new TrickyA();
A<TrickyA> instance2 = new A<TrickyA>();
```